# is it possible to set daynamic name for html control and handle it with php?

Tags: php, html, dynamic, controls

I have this code:

```
<input type="file" class="droparea spot" name="xfile1" data-post="upload.php" data-width="220" data-height="345" data-crop="false"/>
                <input type="file" class="droparea spot" name="xfile2" data-post="upload.php" data-width="220" data-height="345" data-crop="false"/>
                <input type="file" class="droparea spot" name="xfile3" data-post="upload.php" data-width="220" data-height="345" data-crop="false"/>
                <input type="file" class="droparea spot" name="xfile4" data-post="upload.php" data-width="220" data-height="345" data-crop="false"/>
                <input type="file" class="droparea spot" name="xfile5" data-post="upload.php" data-width="220" data-height="345" data-crop="false"/>
```

How to set daynamic control name?
xfile1 or xfile[1] ....?
then how to handel this on php?

$_FILE['xfile[]'];??
Thank you

update:

this is the whole code. its not uploading or showing picture! could you please help?!

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', True);

for ($i=0;$i<=4;$i++)
{
            if ($_FILES['xfile']['name'][$i] <>"") {
            $key=$i;
            }
}




// LOG
$log = '=== ' . @date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ===============================' . "\n"
        . 'FILES:' . print_r($_FILES, 1) . "\n"
        . 'POST:' . print_r($_POST, 1) . "\n";
$fp = fopen('upload-log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $log);
fclose($fp);


// Result object
$r = new stdClass();
// Result content type
header('content-type: application/json');


// Maximum file size
$maxsize = 10; //Mb
// File size control



                    if ($_FILES['xfile']['size'][$key] > ($maxsize * 1048576)) {
                        $r->error = "Max file size: $maxsize Kb";
                    }


// Uploading folder
$folder = 'uploads/';
if (!is_dir($folder))
    mkdir($folder);
// If specifics folder 
$folder .= $_POST['folder'] ? $_POST['folder'] . '/' : '';
if (!is_dir($folder))
    mkdir($folder);


// If the file is an image



                if (preg_match('/image/i', $_FILES['xfile']['type'][$key])) {

                    $filename = $_POST['value'] ? $_POST['value'] :
                            $folder . sha1(@microtime() . '-' . $_FILES['xfile']['name'][$key]) . '.jpg';
                } else {

                    $tld = split(',', $_FILES['xfile']['name'][$key]);
                    $tld = $tld[count($tld) - 1];
                    $filename = $_POST['value'] ? $_POST['value'] :
                            $folder . sha1(@microtime() . '-' . $_FILES['xfile']['name'][$key]) . $tld;
                }


// Supporting image file types
$types = Array('image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg');
// File type control
if (in_array($_FILES['xfile']['type'][$key], $types)) {
    // Create an unique file name    
    // Uploaded file source
    $source = file_get_contents($_FILES["xfile"]["tmp_name"][$key]);
    // Image resize
    imageresize($source, $filename, $_POST['width'], $_POST['height'], $_POST['crop'], $_POST['quality']);
} else
// If the file is not an image
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["xfile"]["tmp_name"][$key], $filename);


// File path
$path = str_replace('upload.php', '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

// Result data
$r->filename = $filename;
$r->path = $path;
$r->img = '<img src="' . $path . $filename . '" alt="image" />';

// Return to JSON
echo json_encode($r);

// Image resize function with php + gd2 lib
function imageresize($source, $destination, $width = 0, $height = 0, $crop = false, $quality = 80) {
    $quality = $quality ? $quality : 80;
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($source);
    if ($image) {
        // Get dimensions
        $w = imagesx($image);
        $h = imagesy($image);
        if (($width && $w > $width) || ($height && $h > $height)) {
            $ratio = $w / $h;
            if (($ratio >= 1 || $height == 0) && $width && !$crop) {
                $new_height = $width / $ratio;
                $new_width = $width;
            } elseif ($crop && $ratio <= ($width / $height)) {
                $new_height = $width / $ratio;
                $new_width = $width;
            } else {
                $new_width = $height * $ratio;
                $new_height = $height;
            }
        } else {
            $new_width = $w;
            $new_height = $h;
        }
        $x_mid = $new_width * .5;  //horizontal middle
        $y_mid = $new_height * .5; //vertical middle
        // Resample
        error_log('height: ' . $new_height . ' - width: ' . $new_width);
        $new = imagecreatetruecolor(round($new_width), round($new_height));
        imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);
        // Crop
        if ($crop) {
            $crop = imagecreatetruecolor($width ? $width : $new_width, $height ? $height : $new_height);
            imagecopyresampled($crop, $new, 0, 0, ($x_mid - ($width * .5)), 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
            //($y_mid - ($height * .5))
        }
        // Output
        // Enable interlancing [for progressive JPEG]
        imageinterlace($crop ? $crop : $new, true);

        $dext = strtolower(pathinfo($destination, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if ($dext == '') {
            $dext = $ext;
            $destination .= '.' . $ext;
        }
        switch ($dext) {
            case 'jpeg':
            case 'jpg':
                imagejpeg($crop ? $crop : $new, $destination, $quality);
                break;
            case 'png':
                $pngQuality = ($quality - 100) / 11.111111;
                $pngQuality = round(abs($pngQuality));
                imagepng($crop ? $crop : $new, $destination, $pngQuality);
                break;
            case 'gif':
                imagegif($crop ? $crop : $new, $destination);
                break;
        }
        @imagedestroy($image);
        @imagedestroy($new);
        @imagedestroy($crop);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Show us how you are creating this code.

Comment: The question is pretty clear.

Comment: You should check the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <form>
        <input type="file" class="droparea spot" name="xfile[]" data-post="upload.php" data-width="220" data-height="345" data-crop="false"/>
        <input type="file" class="droparea spot" name="xfile[]" data-post="upload.php" data-width="220" data-height="345" data-crop="false"/>
        <input type="file" class="droparea spot" name="xfile[]" data-post="upload.php" data-width="220" data-height="345" data-crop="false"/>
        <input type="file" class="droparea spot" name="xfile[]" data-post="upload.php" data-width="220" data-height="345" data-crop="false"/>
        <input type="file" class="droparea spot" name="xfile[]" data-post="upload.php" data-width="220" data-height="345" data-crop="false"/>
    </form>

    ...
    <?php print_r($_FILES['xfile']) ?>

Array(
    0: foo,
    1: foo,
    etc...
```

But recomended use `<input type="file" name="xfile" multiple />`

Remember: php support arrays in file, get and post inputs.

Comment: how to know which input had been triggered in the php file?

Comment: <input type="file" name="xfile[99]" /> : <?php $_FILES['xfile'][99] ?>, remember: it is not asp, dont exist controls and drivers, send all from form in post method, remember encrypt type multipart data.